# In ruby, what kind of object is (x..y)? An enumerator?

Tags: ruby, enumerator

Ive seen this form crop up, for example, as:

```
 (x..y).map { |i| 2*i }.inject(:+)
```

so it seems to be creating an enumerator? But i can't find a definition of the syntax in ruby-docs and it's a hard string to google!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: kind of object == class :)

Comment: wow! an abundance of amazingly useful responses to a clearly noddy question. thx!

Comment: You posted this question some time ago. If you still want to know how your code is related to enumerators, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thse are Ranges which are described here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_ranges.htm

Or in the official docs they can be found here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Range.html

Answer (score 6):

```
[9] pry(main)> (1..3).class
=> Range
[10] pry(main)> (1..3).class.ancestors
=> [Range, Enumerable, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Comment: Did we pick the same range by coincidence? :)

Comment: I noted too. We both are too lazy for long ranges =)

Answer (score 3):

```
irb(main):001:0> (1..3).class
=> Range
```

And while we are on documentation and stuff, let me suggest [omniref](https://www.omniref.com/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Range&commit=Search)